# Load 2 files .so native lib from 2 different projects in android

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have two projects A  and B. Both of them are using native code.

Now, I set A as a java library.

Then, add Library A into B.

When I run B, Project B can not load native lib in B.

Please give me a instruction!

Comment: Have you copy native library in A to B's 'libs' folder?

Comment: Not yet. A is vitamino   https://www.vitamio.org/en/Download/

Answer (score 0):

I assume "When I run B, Project B can not load native lib in B.", you mean "When I run B, Project B can not load native lib in A.". for this

1) Copy the so files in project A to asset folder
2) Have a class in project A to load the libraries. (Some static function)
3) In libraries init function of A, copy them to the system folder and then load the library.

Below is the code example:

```
public static void copyFileStream(InputStream src, OutputStream dst)  
{
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;

        while ((bytesRead = src.read(buffer)) != -1)
            dst.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static int loadLibraries()
{
    AssetManager assetManager = myContext.getAssets();
    InputStream verLibIn = null;
    OutputStream verLibOut = null; 


    verLibIn = assetManager.open("libLibrary.so");
    verLibOut = myContext.openFileOutput(myContext.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "libLibrary.so", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    copyFileStream(verLibIn, verLibOut);
    verLibIn.close();
    verLibOut.close();

    System.load(myContext.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "libLibrary.so");
}
```

Above code is written for logic purpose. Optimize the same for your use.